# Entity framework (CTP5, Fluent API). Rename column of navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have two entites:

```
public class Address
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; 
 public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Below are mapping classes:

```
public partial class AddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
    {
        public AddressMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Addresses");
            this.HasKey(a => a.Id);
        }
    }
public partial class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Customer");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);

            this.HasOptional<Address>(c => c.BillingAddress);
            this.HasOptional<Address>(c => c.ShippingAddress);
        }
    }
```

When database is generated, my 'Customer' table has two columns for 'BillingAddress' and 'ShippingAddress' properties. Their names are 'AddressId' and 'AddressId1'.
Question: how can I rename them to 'BillingAddressId' and 'ShippingAddressId'?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you want to customize the FK column name in an *independent association* and this code will do this for you:

```
public CustomerMap()
{
    this.ToTable("Customer");            

    this.HasOptional<Address>(c => c.BillingAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .IsIndependent().Map(m => 
        {
            m.MapKey(a => a.Id, "BillingAddressId");                    
        });

    this.HasOptional<Address>(c => c.ShippingAddress)
        .WithMany()
        .IsIndependent().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapKey(a => a.Id, "ShippingAddressId");
        });            
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested. But in my initial post I simplified the model. My customer class has one more property containing a list of all addresses: "public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }". 
And customer configuration class (CustomerMap) has one more line: "this.HasMany<Address>(c => c.Addresses).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("CustomerAddresses"));"
Now I'm getting the following error: "Sequence contains more than one matching element". Any thoughts?

Comment: No problem. I've copied and pasted your additional codes and it perfectly worked for me by creating a new many-to-many association between Customer and Address so I cannot reproduce your exception. Can you please post your complete object model and client code?

Comment: Sure, you can download it here http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets (we're working on the new version of nopCommerce shopping cart) . NOTE: your suggested solution (independent association) is not added to source code yet. Just add it and try to run unit tests

Comment: Well, you need to create a simple console application and try my solution in there which you'll see it perfectly creates the desired schema. But no worries if you didn't, I've done this for you: You can download my sample project from this link and see it for yourself:
http://cid-31fdfaaf183abb01.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=31FDFAAF183ABB01!112

Comment: Morteza, Thanks for your time. Your application works fine. I'll try to find the issue in my model. Although I'm still thinking there's some bug in CTP5

Comment: @and.maz - I am experiencing exactly the same issue as you describe in this scenario - "Sequence contains more than one matching element". Did you find the issue in your model?